# Calculating percentage of landuse type within buffer using Python

Tags: python, geopandas, buffer, overlapping-features, land-use

[image]

I have two polygon shapefiles: buffers and landuse types. I want to calculate the percentage of each landuse type within the respective buffer. The problem is that the landuse type polygons are bigger than the buffers and the buffers often overlap each other.

I want to write a script which sees the buffer individually (storing in a list) and then I want to clip the landuse shapefile to each individual buffer and then calculate the percentage. Does someone have an idea where to start with the Python code?

The picture above is just an example, there are many more polygons and buffers.

Comment: Please choose one environment in which to attempt this code, then make a coding attempt. "R or Python" is two different Question, and neither has a code attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use geopandas with union and groupby:

```
import geopandas as gpd
landuse = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/my_riks_smallsample.shp")
landuse_class_field = "kkod"
zones = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/buffers.shp")
zones["zonearea"] = zones.area

union = gpd.overlay(df1=zones[["zoneid", "zonearea", "geometry"]], df2=landuse[[landuse_class_field,"geometry"]], how="union")
union["unionarea"] = union.area
union = union.groupby(by=["zoneid", landuse_class_field]).agg({"zonearea":"first", "unionarea":"sum"}, as_index=False).reset_index()

print(union.loc[union.zoneid==1])
#    zoneid   kkod      zonearea     unionarea
# 0     1.0  601.0  3.090170e+06  2.126975e+06
# 1     1.0  611.0  3.090170e+06  3.395041e+05
# 2     1.0  901.0  3.090170e+06  8.061800e+03
# 3     1.0  911.0  3.090170e+06  6.156289e+05

union["class_percentage"] = union.apply(lambda x: round(100*x.unionarea/x.zonearea, 1), axis=1)
print(union.loc[union.zoneid==1])
#    zoneid   kkod      zonearea     unionarea  class_percentage
# 0     1.0  601.0  3.090170e+06  2.126975e+06              68.8
# 1     1.0  611.0  3.090170e+06  3.395041e+05              11.0
# 2     1.0  901.0  3.090170e+06  8.061800e+03               0.3
# 3     1.0  911.0  3.090170e+06  6.156289e+05              19.9

#zone 5 is only partially overlapped by land use df, so the percentages doesnt sum to 100:
print(union.loc[union.zoneid==5])
#    zoneid   kkod      zonearea     unionarea  class_percentage
# 7     5.0  601.0  3.090170e+06  1.592287e+06              51.5
# 8     5.0  611.0  3.090170e+06  8.163723e+05              26.4

pivoted = union.pivot(index="zoneid", columns=landuse_class_field, values="class_percentage").fillna(0)
pivoted.head()
kkod    303.0  601.0  611.0  901.0  911.0
zoneid                                   
1.0       0.0   68.8   11.0    0.3   19.9
2.0       0.0  100.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
3.0       0.0    4.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
4.0       0.0   30.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
5.0       0.0   51.5   26.4    0.0    0.0
```

[image]

Comment: I have one question though. I want also the percentage from the total buffer area. In this code you calculate the percentage of the sum of the land use polygons within the area. I need to distinguish it, because the buffer is not fully filled with land use polygons like it is in your case.

Comment: I've changed the answer so it will work for zones where the overlap isnt 100 %

Comment: Thank you for changing it, however, my problem is that the buffer overlapp often and a lot like you can see in my example or even worse. In my results I have percentage of over 100 and I think that is caused by the overlapp. I think a for loop might solve the issue since it takes each buffer one by one. I just dont know how to transform it in to a for loop. And Im not sure if the overlapp is even causing the problem.